# Filtros de una tabla solo funcionan cuando los usuarios hacen parte de cada una de las colecciones de mongodb que integran la tabla

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, codeigniter

Tengo un método en backend php que lo que hace es enviar todos los datos de los usuarios de cada una de las colecciones que correspondan con algunos filtros a una tabla en el frontend con javascript, funciona, pero sólo con los datos de usuarios que contengan valores en todas las colecciones que hagan parte de la tabla, pero, cuando no es así, simplemente sale error en javascript, por lo que antes de pasarlo al frontend, a ese dato que no esté en todas las colecciones lo que hago es añadoirle valores en vacío, pero al hacer eso, ya no filtra correctamente, debido a que ya no se borra toda la fila como tal, sólo se borran las columnas que correspondan a esa colección dentro de la tabla en javascript. No sé cómo podría hacer para que ese dato que no tiene valores en algunas colecciones de la tabla simplemente se llene al menos con datos vacíos, y que a su vez filtre de manera correcta a cuando filtra cuando los datos están en todas las colecciones. :(

Adjunto el método del backend:

```
public function obtenerDatosParaExportarAExcel($post = null){
      $filtroDemograficos = [];
      $filtroAntecedentes = [];
      $filtroSeguimientoMedico = [];
   
      
 
      if($post != null){ //Filtros de cada una de las colecciones
          if($post['Regional'] != "Seleccione una opción"){
              $filtroDemograficos['regional'] = $post['Regional'];
              if($post['Departamento'] != "Seleccione un departamento"){
                  $filtroDemograficos['departamento'] = $post['Departamento'];
                  if(isset($post['municipio']) && $post['municipio'] != "Seleccione un municipio" && $post['municipio'] != null){
                      $filtroDemograficos['municipio'] = $post['municipio'];
                  }
              }
          }
          if($post['fechaDesdeSemanas'] != null){
              if($post['fechaHastaSemanas']){
                  $filtroAntecedentes['semanas_actualizadas']['gte'] = $post['fechaDesdeSemanas'];
                  $filtroAntecedentes['semanas_actualizadas']['lte'] = $post['fechaHastaSemanas'];
              }
             
          }
          if($post['fechaDesdeIngreso'] != null){
              if($post['fechaHastaIngreso']){
                  $filtroAntecedentes['semanas_actualizadas']['gte'] = $post['fechaDesdeIngreso'];
                  $filtroAntecedentes['semanas_actualizadas']['lte'] = $post['fechaHastaIngreso'];
              }
             
          }
          if($post['Priorizado'] != "Seleccione priorización"){
              $filtroSeguimientoMedico['priorizacion_lista'] = $post['Priorizado'];
          }
          if($post['AntecedentesRe'] != "Seleccione un antecedente"){
              $filtroAntecedentes[str_replace(" ", "_", 'reproductivos_'.$post['AntecedentesRe'])] = "on";
          }
          if($post['AntecedentesMedicos'] != "Seleccione un antecedente"){
              $filtroAntecedentes[str_replace(" ", "_", 'medicos_'.$post['AntecedentesMedicos'])] = "on";
          }
      }

      //Obtener una colección que se llama datos demográficos, de ahí se obtienen los ID de los pacientes
      $demograficos = $this->Collection_Model->get_collection('datos_demograficos_maternas', $filtroDemograficos);
      $demograficos = $this->objectToArray($demograficos);  
     
      
      $datos_Total = [];
      foreach($demograficos as $value){ //Recorrer cada uno de los ID que existan dentro del array de datos demográficos

          $filtroDemograficos['id_paciente'] = $value['id_paciente'];
          $filtroAntecedentes['id_paciente'] = $value['id_paciente'];
          $filtroSeguimientoMedico['id_paciente'] = $value['id_paciente'];
           

          //Se obtienen las demás colecciones que se necesitan, filtrándolas también por los ID que existan previamente en la colección de datos demográficos
          
  $demograficosNuevo = $this->Collection_Model->get_collection('datos_demograficos_maternas', $filtroDemograficos);
          $demograficosNuevo = $this->objectToArray($demograficosNuevo); 
          $antecedentes = $this->Collection_Model->get_collection('antecedentes_maternas', $filtroAntecedentes);
          $antecedentes = $this->objectToArray($antecedentes);
          $seguimiento_medico = $this->Collection_Model->get_collection('seguimiento_medico_maternas', $filtroSeguimientoMedico);
          $seguimiento_medico = $this->objectToArray($seguimiento_medico);
     

      //Si alguno de los datos no contiene valor en alguna de las colecciones, se les añade valores vacíos para que no de error

         if(empty($antecedentes)){$antecedentes[0]["_id"] = array('$oid' => "⠀"); $antecedentes[0]['clasificacion_riesgo_gestacional'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['reproductivos_Esterilidad'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['medicos_HTA'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['numero_total_gestaciones'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['fecha_ultimo_parto'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['infecciones_post_parto'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['talla'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['peso_embarazo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['peso_ingreso'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Habitos'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Tabaquismo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Alcohol'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Consumo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['medicamentos'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['medicamento_tomar'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['fum'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['confiabilidad'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['ecoinicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['fecha_eco_inicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['reporte_eco_inicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['observaciones_eco_inicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['e        dad_gestacional_ingreso_eco'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['primer_control_prenatal'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['tipo_embarazo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['criterio_Materno'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['riesgo_gestacional'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['definicion_ctrierio_Edad_>_38_años'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0][0] = "⠀";}  
          if(empty($seguimiento_medico)){$seguimiento_medico[0]["_id"] = array('$oid' => "⠀"); $seguimiento_medico[0]['id_paciente'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['medico_tratante'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['especialidad_perinatologo'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['telefono_seguimiento'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['telefono_seguimiento'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['asiste_uis'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['atencion_eps'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['grupo_sanguineo_materno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['rh_materno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['grupo_sanguineo_paterno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['rh_paterno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['micronutrientes'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['consulta_nutricion'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['consulta_psicologia'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['salud_oral'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['dental_elite'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['observaciones'] = "⠀";}

       // Se añaden las colecciones dentro de un arreglo con un array_push con cada una de las colecciones dentro de la tabla
      
          array_push($datos_Total, array("datos_demograficos_maternas" => $demograficosNuevo, "antecedentes_maternas" => $antecedentes, "seguimiento_medico_maternas" => $seguimiento_medico, "vacunacion_maternas" => $vacunacion, "primer_trimestre_maternas" => $primetrimestre, "segundo_trimestre_maternas" => $segundotrimestre, "tercer_trimestre_maternas" => $tercertrimestre, "hospitalizaciones_maternas" => $hospitalizaciones, "remisiones_maternas" => $remisiones, "parto_maternas" => $partos, "llamadas_maternas" => $llamadas, "capacitaciones_maternas" => $capacitaciones, "puerperio_maternas" => $puerperio, "partos_maternas" => $partos, "seguimiento_final_caso_maternas" => $seguimientoFinal));

  }

// Se envian al frontend
      $data['datosTotal'] = $datos_Total;
      return $data;

  }
```

Lo que retorna hacia el frontend por cada fila es esta estructura, donde las columnas son cada una de las colecciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí en la tabla en Javascript es donde intento mostrar la información:

```
Object.entries(nuevosDatosUsuarios).map(resp =>{
        console.log(resp);
        
        Object.entries(resp[1]).map(usuario =>{
    
            /*console.log(usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento']);*/
           
        
        txt += `<tr class='text-center'>
        <!-- demograficos-->
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['tipo_identificacion'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['tipo_identificacion'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['regional'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['regional'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['direccion'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['direccion'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['telefono'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['telefono'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['telefono'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['telefono'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['correo_electronico'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['correo_electronico'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['departamento'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['departamento'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['municipio'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['municipio'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['sucursal'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['sucursal'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['programa'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['programa'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['eps'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['eps'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['via_ingreso'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['via_ingreso'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['nivel_educativo'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['nivel_educativo'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['ocupacion'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['ocupacion'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['riesgo_laboral'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['riesgo_laboral'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['colectivo'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['colectivo'] : "N/A"}</td>
    
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['reproductivos_RCIU'] === "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas']['reproductivos_RCIU'] : "N/A"} </td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['medicos_HTA'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas']['medicos_HTA'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['definicion_riesgo_obs'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['definicion_riesgo_obs'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['tipo_embarazo'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['tipo_embarazo'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_ultimo_parto'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_ultimo_parto'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['infecciones_post_parto'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['infecciones_post_parto'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['talla'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['talla'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['numero_total_gestaciones'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['numero_total_gestaciones'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_embarazo'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_embarazo'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['talla'] && usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_embarazo'] != "undefined" ?  usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_embarazo']/Math.pow(usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['talla'], 2): "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_ingreso'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_ingreso'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['talla'] && usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_ingreso'] != "undefined" ?  usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['peso_ingreso']/Math.pow(usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['talla'], 2): "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Habitos'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Habitos'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Tabaquismo'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Tabaquismo'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Alcohol'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Alcohol'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Consumo'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['Consumo'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['medicamentos'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['medicamentos'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['medicamento_tomar'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['medicamento_tomar'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['confiabilidad'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['confiabilidad'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['ecoinicial'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['ecoinicial'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_eco_inicial'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_eco_inicial'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['reporte_eco_inicial'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['reporte_eco_inicial'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['observaciones_eco_inicial'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['observaciones_eco_inicial'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['edad_gestacional_ingreso_Fum'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['edad_gestacional_ingreso_Fum'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['edad_gestacional_ingreso_eco'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['edad_gestacional_ingreso_eco'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['semanas_actualizadas'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['semanas_actualizadas'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['trimestre_ingreso'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['trimestre_ingreso'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_proba_parto_fum'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_proba_parto_fum'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_proba_parto_eco'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['fecha_proba_parto_eco'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['clasificacion_riesgo_obs'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['antecedentes_maternas'][0]['clasificacion_riesgo_obs'] : "N/A"}</td>
        
        <!-- Seguimiento médico-->
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['priorizacion_lista'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['priorizacion_lista'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['medico_tratante'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['medico_tratante'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['especialidad_medico_general'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['especialidad_medico_general'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['telefono_seguimiento'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['telefono_seguimiento'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['asiste_uis'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['asiste_uis'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['atencion_eps'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['atencion_eps'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['grupo_sanguineo_materno'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['grupo_sanguineo_materno'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['rh_materno'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['rh_materno'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['grupo_sanguineo_paterno'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['grupo_sanguineo_paterno'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['rh_paterno'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['rh_paterno'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['micronutrientes'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['micronutrientes'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['consulta_nutricion'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['consulta_nutricion'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['consulta_psicologia'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['consulta_psicologia'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['salud_oral'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['salud_oral'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['dental_elite'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['dental_elite'] : "N/A"}</td>
                <td>${typeof usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['observaciones'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['seguimiento_medico_maternas'][0]['observaciones'] : "N/A"}</td>
    </tr>`
    })});
    
    $("#datatable").append(txt);
```

Cuando ejecuto el código de arriba, y le aplico los filtros para que borren toda la fila, lo que hace es que simplemente me cambia los valores de la colección dentro de la tabla a vacío:

Antes de aplicar el filtro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez: aplicado el filtro que no corresponda a ningún dato, lo que hace es borrar los datos que correspondían a esa colección dentro de la tabla, pero las otras colecciones que hacen parte de la tabla simplemente siguen igual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debería hacer es borrar toda la fila.

Ahora, cuando remuevo esta parte del backend que está arriba:

```
//Si alguno de los datos no contiene valor en alguna de las colecciones, se les añade valores vacíos para que no de error

       if(empty($antecedentes)){$antecedentes[0]["_id"] = array('$oid' => "⠀"); $antecedentes[0]['clasificacion_riesgo_gestacional'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['reproductivos_Esterilidad'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['medicos_HTA'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['numero_total_gestaciones'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['fecha_ultimo_parto'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['infecciones_post_parto'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['talla'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['peso_embarazo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['peso_ingreso'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Habitos'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Tabaquismo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Alcohol'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['Consumo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['medicamentos'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['medicamento_tomar'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['fum'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['confiabilidad'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['ecoinicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['fecha_eco_inicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['reporte_eco_inicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['observaciones_eco_inicial'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['e        dad_gestacional_ingreso_eco'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['primer_control_prenatal'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['tipo_embarazo'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['criterio_Materno'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['riesgo_gestacional'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0]['definicion_ctrierio_Edad_>_38_años'] = "⠀"; $antecedentes[0][0] = "⠀";}  
        if(empty($seguimiento_medico)){$seguimiento_medico[0]["_id"] = array('$oid' => "⠀"); $seguimiento_medico[0]['id_paciente'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['medico_tratante'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['especialidad_perinatologo'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['telefono_seguimiento'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['telefono_seguimiento'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['asiste_uis'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['atencion_eps'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['grupo_sanguineo_materno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['rh_materno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['grupo_sanguineo_paterno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['rh_paterno'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['micronutrientes'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['consulta_nutricion'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['consulta_psicologia'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['salud_oral'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['dental_elite'] = "⠀"; $seguimiento_medico[0]['observaciones'] = "⠀";}
```

Genera este error, como si no existiera esa parte dentro del arreglo que proviene del backend:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he intentado es mediante un if comprobar si en ese dato el arreglo no está vacío, para que no genere el error:

```
if($usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas']){
        txt += `<tr class='text-center'>
        <!-- demograficos-->
        
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['fecha_nacimiento'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['tipo_identificacion'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['tipo_identificacion'] : "N/A"}</td>
        <td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['regional'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['regional'] : "N/A"}</td>
        td>${typeof usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['direccion'] != "undefined" ? usuario[1]['datos_demograficos_maternas'][0]['direccion'] : "N/A"}</td>
        `
    }else{
        txt += `<tr class='text-center'>
        <!-- demograficos-->
        
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        td>0</td>
        `
    }
```

pero eso lo que hace es omitir el dato vacío y me muestra solo los que están con los datos que contienen valores en todas las colecciones

Por favor si alguien me podría colaborar, de verdad que se lo agradecería muchísimo.